# STL priority_queue in increasing order syntax

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I checked out that to obtain an STL priority_queue in increasing order we need to declare it in this way:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> q;
```

Can somebody explain me this syntax? What this `vector<int>` (why vector?) and `greater<int>` stand for?

Comment: did you check the [official documentation?](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/)

Comment: @Desh_Er_Bojha There is nothing official about cplusplus.com. The only definitive documentation is the language standard. You can download a current working draft of the standard from [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/).

Comment: It may not be official, but it's certainly much more useful, from a documentation standpoint, than reading the standard. Even if it has some errors now and then.

Answer (score 1):

The `vector<int>` is the underlying container. The `priority_queue<>` is an adapter.

See

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue